# Create custom field using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have data for custom field as

```
var data = [
            {type:"text",fieldName:"UserName",fieldValue:"bob"},
            {type:"text",fieldName:"password",fieldValue:"bob"}
           ]
```

Problem is when I created custom field, how I can use `ng-model` as I am using `ng-repeat` to create custom field.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2xHiIFXEuZ5Hz0J6CUkq?p=preview)

> I don't want to bind fieldValue only but also want to modified UserName and Password
>
> data is dynamic.

**Notes**

> I want to pass username and password to server via controller.
>
> Here **UserName** and **Password** label is just an example, it may be **Email Id, Telephone Number** or anything.

I want data as `{UserName:"test",Password:"123456abcd"}`

If I have Email Id field name then my data should be `{Email : "abcd@xyz.com"}` on controller

so I can use $http to send data to server like :

```
$http.post('myUrl',data).then(function(response){
           console.log(responce);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-model="c.fieldValue"
```

since you want the field to be populated with the `fieldValue` attribute of the currend element of the array: `c` (and vice-versa).

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjwLQO2jaMgQfmMvo5by?p=preview)

When you submit your form, just iterate through your field to create your object to submit:

```
var command = {};
angular.forEach(data, function(field) {
    command[field.fieldName] = field.fieldValue;
});
$http.post('myUrl',command).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to bind fieldValue only but also want to modified UserName and Password. My mistake, I didn't given this details in question.

Comment: I don't understand. You would also like to have an input field to change the `fieldName` attribute of each object in data? Well, do the same thing, but use `ng-model="c.fieldName"` instead.

Comment: No, not filedName but fieldValue to be change.

Comment: So, exactly what I did in my answer, and demonstrated in my plunkr. What should be different from what I suggested?

Comment: Thanks sir, this is what I want.

Comment: Pls update your `plunkr` so its not create confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use is **bracket notation**. It works as follows:

```
 var objToSendToServer;
 objToSendToServer[c.fieldName] = c.fieldValue;
```

More info at this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

I think the final code should look something like this:

```
var objToSendToServer;
data.forEach(function(){
    objToSendToServer[c.fieldName] = c.fieldValue;
});
```